# Calculating On-time delivery KPI in PowerBI Report

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I have a following table which contains two columns of dates

| Cust Promised Date | Act Delivery Date |
| --- | --- |
| CPDate1 | ADDate1 |
| CPDate2 | ADDate2 |

I have created a new column that provides the difference between two columns in terms of days

| Cust Promised Date | Act Delivery Date | Diff Days |
| --- | --- | --- |
| CPDate1 | ADDate1 | Diff1 |
| CPDate2 | ADDate2 | Diff2 |

Where Diff1 is calculated as Days(CPDate1 - ADDate1). This value can be positive, negative and NULL sometimes due to incomplete data.

I want to calculate a On-time delivery KPI that is calculated as

```
on-time KPI = (count of Diff Days >= 0 AND <> NULL)/(Total count of values in Diff Days Column <> NULL) * 100
```

I want to display this metric as a scorecard or a KPI visual. This metric should dynamically change with the slicer used in the dashboard. However, I not sure how to calculate this in PowerBI. I have been looking into "Quick Measure" (on column Diff Days) and DAX expressions.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, Here we start! Please check my code for your problem:

Now This is the Diff Days Calculated Column Code:

```
Diff Days = 
if(
    OR(ISBLANK([Cust Promised Date]), ISBLANK([Act Delivery Date])),BLANK(),
    [Cust Promised Date] - [Act Delivery Date])
```

If we test it with dummy data, It gives us:

[image: Timescale]

Then You can write your Measure as DAX CODE like this:

```
On_Time Delivery = 
VAR Part_01 = CALCULATE(
   COUNT(TimeScale[Diff Days]),
   TimeScale[Diff Days] >=0)
VAR Part_02 = CALCULATE(
   COUNT(TimeScale[Diff Days]),
   ALL(TimeScale))
RETURN
DIVIDE(
   Part_01,Part_02)
```

If we put it on a table visual(You can put it in a scorecard visual or whatever you prefer)

[image: Truman_Gold Sach]

I hope This solves your problem:

Note: You need to understand that ETL(Power Query) is critical before this process, so you need to move out the data which is null or other bad or unknown data. You can only check if values are blank or not in a comparison with date values: